# Creating contract issue. Contract keeps loading

Tags: mist, contract-debugging

I'm testing the process of creating an Ethereum contract using the Mist Rinkeby test Network. I used the code from an online tutorial, everything went fine, except at the creation of the contract.

The contract stays on "Creating contract" status for more than 24 hours now where it is supposed to take few minutes.

The transaction says that there are more than 4677 block confirmations but I can't still execute the contract as it is still in "creating" status.

[image: loading status]

Please see the TX link below:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x34f2b0cac6803a95a99240f70768f650ffec46d98a95be0455c49ba05bac1b02

Note that I am using Mist 0.9.1 on Mac OS 10.12.6.

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: FYI, here is the video of the online tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC-bDQZbXd0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by setting the maximum possible fee in Mist when I deployed my contract. It took about 5 minutes but it eventually was created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Richard. I actually tested on the new version of MIST which works with a regular fee amount